# Computing Average Number of Successes When Randomness is Involved

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am attempting to write a program that will compute the average amount of a particular product produced when randomness is involved.

Let's say that I am trying to produce some widget. Whenever the production process for this widget is started, it is not guaranteed that the process will be successful. So let's say that the probability of successfully producing a widget is `P(s)`. However, you only start with `M` number of materials, and whenever a widget is successfully created, then `C` materials are used up. Similarly, whenever a widget fails to be prodeced `L` materials are used up.

So we know the following:

```
 P(s) = probability that production process will yield a widget.
  M   = Amount of starting materials
  C   = Amount of materials used if widget successfully created.
  L   = Amount of materials lost if failure to make widget.</code>
```

The problem I am having is in trying to compute the average number of widgets created (and similarly, the average number of failed widgets) given different values for `P(s)`, `M`, `C`, and `L`.

How can I come up with an equation that gives me the average successes and failures to create widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an approximation, one attempt will on average produce a fraction $P(s)$ of a widget (let's call it $P$ for short) and consume $PC +(1-P)L$ of material.

So you can have about $\dfrac{M}{PC +(1-P)L}$ attempts and so will produce about $\dfrac{PM}{PC +(1-P)L}$ widgets.  Write it as $\dfrac{M}{C +\left(\frac{1-P}P\right)L}$ widgets if that helps your understanding of the waste involved with failures: it would be $\frac{M}{C}$ if $P=1$ and there are no failures.

You probably cannot in fact produce fractions of a widget, so this will be a slight overestimate of the true expected number, but it should give a reasonable view of the order of magnitude involved.

Comment: I tested your approach with a small test case of 5 starting materials, P(s) = 0.75, C = 1, and L = 5. I included the test case into my original question above. I also ran the numbers on the small test case.  If I run those numbers into your equations I get 2.5 attempts on average, and 1.875 widgets made on average, which doesn't match the manual calculations I made above. Also, it doesn't work out empirically. I wrote a program that produced widgets using the probabilities given above. The program confirms the numbers I calculated by hand above. Therefore, I think your equations have an error.

Comment: The problem with such a small test case is that you hit an anomaly almost immediately: if you have from $1$ to $4$ successes followed by a failure then you end up with negative material, which is meaningless. Suppose alternatively that each attempt requires the larger of $L$ or $C$ to start and then you get back the difference $|L-C|$ if the cheaper event occurs; then the expected number of successes in your example is only $0.75$.  Clearly $1.875$ is between $0.75$ and $2.2881$.

Comment: I see your point. I ran my computer simulation with much larger numbers and, as you implied in your comment, the larger the starting the materials, the closer my simulated results got to the results produced by your equations. I removed the misleading test case.